# Forming a list out of two lists with certain pattern in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists like this

```
lst1 = [["a","b"],[1,2,3],[7,8,9,10,11]]
lst2 = [["c","d"],[4,5,6],[12,13,14,15,16]]
```

I am trying to achieve something like this **OUTPUT:**

```
[["a","b","c","d"],[1,2,4,5],[2,3,5,6],[7,8,12,13],[8,9,13,14],[9,10,14,15],[10,11,15,16]]
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry for not including what i have tried till now.

```
test = list(zip(lst1,lst2))
test2 = [item for sublist in test for items in sublist for item in items]

def split(lst, size = 1):
    lsts = []
    while len(lst) > size:
        piece = lst[:size]
        lsts.append(piece)
        lst = lst[size:]
    lsts.append(lst)
    return lsts

print (split(test2, 4))

# prints this 

[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried before asking how to do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this works, assuming that the lists are formatted correctly, ie all sublists are same length as the equivalent one in the other array.

```
lst1 = [["a","b"],[1,2,3],[7,8,9,10,11]]
lst2 = [["c","d"],[4,5,6],[12,13,14,15,16]]

output = []
for s1, s2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
    if len(s1) <= 2:
        output.append(s1 + s2)
    else:
        for index in range(0, len(s1)-1):
            output.append(s1[index:index+2] + s2[index:index+2])

print(output)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8, 12, 13], [8, 9, 13, 14], [9, 10, 14, 15], [10, 11, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but the code works just as well if you remove the conditional and leave only the `else` part inside of the loop.

Comment: Yes I realise, for some (irrational) reason I prefer having the conditional there, but you are correct, the if statement can be removed entirely @jdehesa

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a slightly complicated list comprehension and a helper function from `itertools` recipes called [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise):

```
import itertools as it

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = it.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

>>> [x + y for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2) for x, y in zip(pairwise(a), pairwise(b))]
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
 (1, 2, 4, 5),
 (2, 3, 5, 6),
 (7, 8, 12, 13),
 (8, 9, 13, 14),
 (9, 10, 14, 15),
 (10, 11, 15, 16)]
```